# Hidden characters in InDesign affecting alignment

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, alignment

I'm working on an InDesign file (possibly from an older version, it's been a minute since the file was used), and when center aligning the text, it appears that the hidden characters or "invisibles" are being treated as if they have width — therefore affecting the alignment.

Hiding the invisibles does nothing, and attempting to resize the text boxes even a pixel or two before the edge of the characters sends the entire word off into oblivion.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've complained to Adobe about this for years... it's a problem in several of their apps.

Answer (score 1):

Invisible Characters shouldn't affect the size of a text box in InDesign. I'd suggest there may be a space at the end of your sentence, but I can't see a 'dot'.

Try the following:

- Make sure there isn't a right-indent applied to the paragraph.
- Select the text box and double-click on the bottom-right handle. This will snap the box to fit the text.

Hopefully one of these helps!

Comment: I've tried — it also affects longer, multi-line paragraphs. Spaces and line breaks also seem to have width. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you've got some serious kerning/tracking applied, so that might be making a difference too. Also, some fonts just have awkward spacing.

Comment: It's a bit of a clumsy workaround, but you could try adding a left-indent to your text to compensate?

Comment: Even with kerning and tracking taken out, the characters still render as having width.

Answer (score 0):

@Hank I agree with @Alex.  Looks like you have some kerning issues. I would select all and zero out your kerning.  Just tried it and I'm getting it center without issue.

Comment: Unfortunately that does nothing. It seems they are being rendered as actual characters.